# View is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, ios8, keywindow

I'm encountering with a weird issue on iOS 8 the latest beta.
My view is disappearing from the window hierarchy in oppose to iOS7 - basically I'm replacing my `UINavigationController` with a new one at some point.
This code worked with no issues until iOS 8 , any idea why?
If I'm adding the `UINavigationController` to the `keyWindow` - it actually bypass this issue and the view actually "stays" in the window hierarchy :

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myUINavigationController];
```

But I don't like this "hack".

Comment: How were you doing it before?

Comment: Well I'm allocating a new view controller and then I use the presentViewController for showing it.

Comment: Have you tried just assigning the new view controller to your windows' `rootViewController` property?

Comment: No, I'll try that. But just to make it clear - you  meant without using the presentViewController ?

Comment: Actually this UINavigationController shouldn't be the root view controller of the my app - we have some other viewconroller which should be the root view controller.

Comment: Why add a new navigation controller?  You could just replace the views that are in the current one via `setViewControllers:`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
self.window.rootViewController = myUINavigationController;
```

Comment: As I wrote in the above comments , the UINavigationController shouldn't be the root view controller of the my app - we have some other viewconroller which should be the root view controller.

Comment: What's the point of this? What is your use case? Why not present it modally?

Comment: I actually use the presentModalViewController (presentViewController after deprecation) in order to show it modally, but from some reason the view is removed from the window hierarchy - notice that this isn't the case in lower iOS version...

Comment: Also, presenting a modal view controller works just fine for me in iOS8. Show some code, you're likely doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I'm meant that I'm using the presentViewController instead of the presentModalViewController

Comment: I'm looking for the cause to this behaviour - will keep you updated.